# C#: Custom Delegate but the first parameter is given

Tags: c#, callback, delegates, .net-7.0

I want to store callbacks for WebSocket calls from the clientside.
I want to tell the IDE the first param should always be `ClientMetadata`.

The problem is, that I want to register methods which would have infinite amount and unknown type of parameters but the first must be a ClientMetadata object.

I want to register the callbacks like this:

```cs
RegisterEventHandler("callback1", (ClientMetadata client, string smth1, int smth2);
RegisterEventHandler("callback2", (ClientMetadata client, bool smth3);
```

I have a method to store callbacks:

```cs
public static void RegisterEventHandler(string identifier, Delegate callback)
{
    callbacks.Add(identifier, callback);
}
```

Here is where the callbacks are stored:

```cs
private static Dictionary<string, EventHandlerCallback> callbacks = new Dictionary<string, EventHandlerCallback>();
```

Here is how the stored methods get invoked:

```cs
private static void Server_MessageReceive2d(object? sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string jsonObj = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Data);

    if (jsonObj != null)
    {
        WSMessage obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WSMessage>(jsonObj);

        if (obj == null || obj.message == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        //obj.identifier is the id of the callback in the serverside
        if (callbacks.ContainsKey(obj.identifier))
        {
            MethodInfo mi = callbacks[obj.identifier].GetMethodInfo();

            if (obj.callbackId != null && mi.ReturnType.ToString() != "System.Void")
            {
                //e.Client --> ClientMetaData
                //obj.message --> dynamic[]?
                var ret = callbacks[obj.identifier].DynamicInvoke(e.Client, obj.message);
                
                //obj.callbackId is the callback to call when the method ended
                if (ret != null)
                {
                    SendMessage(e.Client, obj.callbackId, ret);
                }
                else
                {
                    SendMessage(e.Client, obj.callbackId);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                callbacks[obj.identifier].DynamicInvoke(e.Client, obj.message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried making a custom delegate:

```cs
delegate void EventHandlerCallback(ClientMetadata clientMetadata, params object[] data);
```

Turns out, the `params` keyword does absolutely nothing in this situation. Either ways I use `params` or not, my IDE expects this:

```cs
RegisterEventHandler("callback2", (ClientMetadata client, object[] smthObj);
```

Comment: How would one of those callbacks be invoked?

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, the invoke code segment is in the edited post.

Comment: In your calling code you only ever pass exactly two parameters, both of a statically known type.  There is not a dynamic number of parameters, nor any unknown types involved.

Comment: you may do runtime checks inside `RegisterEventHandler` like `if(callback.Method.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType != typeof(ClientMetadata))
  throw new ArgumentException("Wrong delegate");` ... I do not see a way to do this statically at compile time without  writing code analyzer

Comment: I tought of that, but Is there a way to tell my IDE that the first parameter should always be `ClientMetadata`?

Comment: I don't think you can force a compiler error, but you could write a custom analyzer & throw a runtime error. If you could do it, `Func<>` wouldn't have so many overloaded types.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman in fact code analyzer can raise an error and not allow to compile ...

Comment: Sure you can opt-in to allow an analyzer diagnostic message to fail your build. I wouldn't call that a compiler error though.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a delegate that takes a ClientMetadata object as the first argument and an array of objects as the second argument. This way, you can store callbacks with any number of unknown parameters:

```
delegate void EventHandlerCallback(ClientMetadata clientMetadata, object[] data);

public static void RegisterEventHandler(string identifier, 
EventHandlerCallback callback)
{
    callbacks.Add(identifier, callback);
}
```

// Usage:

```
RegisterEventHandler("callback1", (ClientMetadata client, object[] args) => 
{
    string smth1 = (string)args[0];
    int smth2 = (int)args[1];
});

RegisterEventHandler("callback2", (ClientMetadata client, object[] args) => 
{
    bool smth3 = (bool)args[0];
});
```

Comment: This solution would be good eventually but it's kinda hard to use when you're scripting an eventhandler.

I want to declare the params independently like this:
`RegisterEventHandler("callback1", (ClientMetadata client, string smth1, int smth2);`

Answer (score -3):

You can go for Code Analyzer... Something like this should do the trick:

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Immutable;

namespace AnalyzerTest
{
    [DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
    public class AnalyzerTestAnalyzer : DiagnosticAnalyzer
    {
        public const string ExpectedParameterType = "ClientMetadata";
        public const string MethodName = "RegisterEventHandler";

        public const string DiagnosticId = "SEL001";
        public const string Title = "AnalyzerTest";
        public const string MessageFormat = "Method call '{0}' wrong argument. First parameter of delegate should be '{1}'";
        public const string Category = "Error";

        private static readonly DiagnosticDescriptor Rule = new DiagnosticDescriptor(DiagnosticId, Title, MessageFormat, Category, DiagnosticSeverity.Error, isEnabledByDefault: true);

        public override ImmutableArray<DiagnosticDescriptor> SupportedDiagnostics { get { return ImmutableArray.Create(Rule); } }

        public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
        {
            context.ConfigureGeneratedCodeAnalysis(GeneratedCodeAnalysisFlags.Analyze);
            context.EnableConcurrentExecution();
            context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(NodeAction, new SyntaxKind[] { SyntaxKind.InvocationExpression });
        }

        private void NodeAction(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
        {
            var registerMethodSymbol = (IMethodSymbol)context.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(context.Node).Symbol;
            if(registerMethodSymbol.Name == MethodName)
            {
                IMethodSymbol methodSymbol;
                var callbackSyntax = ((InvocationExpressionSyntax)context.Node).ArgumentList.Arguments[1];
                var callbackTypeInfo = context.SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo(callbackSyntax.Expression);
                if(callbackTypeInfo.Type != null)
                {
                    var namedType = callbackTypeInfo.Type as INamedTypeSymbol;
                    //Action<ClientMetadata, ...> or Func<ClientMetadata, ..., ret> or delegate
                    methodSymbol = namedType.DelegateInvokeMethod;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Method
                    var symbolInfo = context.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(callbackSyntax.Expression);
                    methodSymbol = (symbolInfo.Symbol ?? (symbolInfo.CandidateSymbols != null ? symbolInfo.CandidateSymbols[0] : null)) as IMethodSymbol;

                }
                if(methodSymbol != null && methodSymbol.Parameters.Length > 0 && methodSymbol.Parameters[0].Type.Name == ExpectedParameterType)
                {
                    return;
                }
                var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, callbackSyntax.GetLocation(), MethodName, ExpectedParameterType);
                context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is example how it works (of course it causing compile time error)
[image: Example]

Comment: Hello, Sorry for my late reply. I didn't have much time for this project lately. Could you send me the full code? I'm sorry, but I can't understand how should I implement your solution.